# What is the `||` operator used for when creating a new Tokio TcpServer?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I've been experimenting with the [Tokio libraries](https://tokio.rs/) for playing with TCP servers and clients. A server is almost always constructed like so:

```
TcpServer::new(Http, addr)
    .serve(|| Ok(HelloWorld));
```

I'm curious to know what the `||` operator does and how it's used in this expression?

Here are some [complete server examples based on Tokio MiniHTTP](https://github.com/natemurthy/misc/blob/master/rust/tokio-minihttp/examples).

Comment: It is a closure function. Is the confusion just that it's not obvious it is a function with no arguments, or are you unfamiliar with those?

Comment: That is actually a closure statement with an empty parameter list.